# Why is the space key being filtered out by MUI's Text Field component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I place one of [MUI's Text Field components](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/) inside the column header of a [Data Grid component](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/), I'm unable to type a space into the text field. Similarly, if I press the right or left arrow key while the text field has focus, the text field loses focus rather than changing the position of the cursor within the text field.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cant-add-space-to-muis-textfield-erpvc?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const rows = [
    { id: 1, "Column 1": 1, "Column 2": 2 },
    { id: 2, "Column 1": 3, "Column 2": 4 },
    { id: 3, "Column 1": 4, "Column 2": 5 }
  ];
  const createColumn = (name) => {
    return {
      field: name,
      align: "center",
      editable: true,
      sortable: false
    };
  };
  const columns = [
    createColumn("Column 1"),
    createColumn("Column 2"),
    {
      field: "Add a split",
      width: 225,
      sortable: false,
      renderHeader: (params) => {
        return (
          <TextField
            placeholder="Enter column name"
            size="small"
            onKeyDown={(event) => console.log("Key down: ", event.key)}
            onKeyUp={(event) => console.log("Key up: ", event.key)}
            onKeyPress={(event) => console.log("Key press: ", event.key)}
          />
        );
      }
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DataGrid
        className="App-data-grid"
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        disableSelectionOnClick
        disableColumnMenu
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Kudos on giving sandbox link. Add your code here too. Links might break in future.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the [accessibility portion of the documentation](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/accessibility/#keyboard-navigation), you can find keyboard navigation details for the data grid. Arrow keys are used to navigate between cells and <kbd>space</kbd> (among other things) is used to navigate to the next scrollable page. You can find the handling of those keys in the [handleCellNavigationKeyDown function in useGridKeyboardNavigation.ts](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/v5.5.0/packages/grid/_modules_/grid/hooks/features/keyboard/useGridKeyboardNavigation.ts#L163).

When a key down event happens for one of those special navigation characters, MUI calls `event.preventDefault()` which in your case prevents the key from having its default effect within the input. You can prevent that by using `event.stopPropagation()` within the TextField `onKeyDown` such that the event never reaches the grid's keyboard navigation handling code. Keep in mind though that by doing this, you may be harming some of the keyboard accessibility features.

Here's a modified version of your sandbox demonstrating this: https://codesandbox.io/s/cant-add-space-to-muis-textfield-33joy?file=/src/App.js:863-902.

Comment: You're a life saver,
I was facing the same problem, i had built a custom dropdown in the MUI Datagrid and had a textfield inside, everytime i would press spacebar the entire page would scroll to the right and had no clue why...

your codesandbox helped me overcome this.

I had a question about the difference b/w keydown,keyup, and keypress but my colleague explained it to me so this is just a thank you comment at this point :P

Answer (score -1):

I had similar luck with just adding event.stopPropagation() to the DataGrid onCellKeyDown prop.  This works generally for any renderCell.

```
((_cell, event) => {
   if (event.KeyCode === 32) event.stopPropagation
```